# How to create a low memory footprint JSON writer?

Tags: java, json, servlets, memory, out-of-memory

I have a HTTP GET servlet set up that returns JSON encoded DICOM image (medical images) but I run out of memory while returning the response since JSON output stream ends up copying the whole thing as shown bellow in bold in the exception stack frame.

> ERROR | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,068 |  - Exception in thread
>   "http-bio-8080-exec-1"   ERROR | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,068 |  -
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space  ERROR | 2016-03-29
>   14:08:45,068 |  -     at **java.util.Arrays.copyOf**(Arrays.java:2882)  ERROR
>   | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,068 |  -    at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
>   ERROR | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
>   ERROR | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)  ERROR |
>   2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:84)  ERROR | 2016-03-29
>   14:08:45,069 |  -     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.writeValue(JSONObject.java:1562)  ERROR |
>   2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   org.json.JSONArray.write(JSONArray.java:929)  ERROR | 2016-03-29
>   14:08:45,069 |  -     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.writeValue(JSONObject.java:1553)  ERROR |
>   2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1626)  ERROR | 2016-03-29
>   14:08:45,069 |  -     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.writeValue(JSONObject.java:1551)  ERROR |
>   2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:1609)  ERROR | 2016-03-29
>   14:08:45,069 |  -     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:1420)  ERROR | 2016-03-29
>   14:08:45,069 |  -     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:1397)  ERROR | 2016-03-29
>   14:08:45,069 |  -     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826) 
>   ERROR | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.print(CoyoteWriter.java:248)
>   ERROR | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   com.tiasl.ImageViewerServlet.doGet(ImageViewerServlet.java:196)
>   ERROR | 2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  ERROR |
>   2016-03-29 14:08:45,069 |  -  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

To create the output stream I use the response writer like this:

```
// Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
// Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, perform the following, it will return your json object  
out.print(jsonObj);
```

So, is there any other more efficient way to stream quite large JSON objects without running out of memory? This is a very frustrating situation since it bottlenecks my concurrent number of users. We already have 2 servers and since JSON is ultimately text, how can this be streamed in chunks?

### EDIT 1

This application sends medical images ranging from 500KB to 200MB. Most of them will be around 1MB. We use a Java application server endpoint to stream images back to a web page. This our first non optimized draft so we wanted a simple approach.

We request images using JS like so:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", parsedId.url + "?quality=" + parsedId.requestedQuality + "&v=" + startTime, false);
xhr.responseType = 'text';
xhr.timeout = timeout;     
xhr.send();
if (!(xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 206)) {
    throw Error(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + ": " + parsedId.url);
}
endTime = Date.now();
stats.downloadTime += (endTime - startTime);

stats.fileSize = xhr.responseText.length;
var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: Have you verified that the JSON conversion is what is in fact taking up most of the memory? I would be quite shocked if the StringBuilder instance building your JSON response is in fact the largest object in the heap. With a 50MB per thread limit, that would be a TON of JSON text.

Comment: How big are these images?  Note that image data is a terrible thing to transfer as JSON, because each pixel's color/intensity components are generally encoded as UTF-8 text, which roughly triples the size, and that doesn't account for the overhead of JSON markup; I would expect at least a 5x multiple for original size to JSON size, and possibly as high as 10x in memory while constructing it since Strings are immutable in Java (your JSON writer looks to build a tree of strings, then collapse that tree into a different string using a StringWriter/StringBuffer).

Comment: One more question: are you required to send the images with JSON?  It looks like you are using Java for both the source and destination, so e.g. could you open a binary tcp channel and stream the images instead?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: If the json object is actually only the image and no other data, you *can* send and receive it as binary. Use `resp.getOutputStream()` in the server and use the techniques described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) in the client.